# C - Printing weird

Tags: c, random, printf

When I compile my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j;
    float broj;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for (i=0; i<=n; ++i) {
        j=i;
        broj = 0.1 * j;
        while (j>=0) {
            printf ("%3.1f ", broj-(j*0.1));
            j--;
        }
        printf(" %d. red\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It after 5th row begins printing first number as -0.0 instead of 0.0, every 2nd row, so its like that in 5th, 7th, 9th etc...

Comment: What s the goal of this code? What is it meant to do?

Comment: Can you please provide the input and the expected output as well?

Comment: Also, have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger, line by line? It might help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: If your input is 3, output should be:

Comment: [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20399193/edit) your question and add.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like some basic floating-point precision problems. Note that 0.1 is not exactly representable as a `float`, so every time you use it you are going to be using an approximation of it.

This means that repeated calculations using 0.1 like your code are going to also be repeating the approximation error, which might lead to the end result being slightly off from what you might expect if you did the same calculations by hand.

A good reference is, as always [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Looks an interesting topic this ! , what do you mean 0.1 is not exactly representable as a float ?

Comment: @Srikanth See the link I added, and also read [this section of the Wikipedia page on floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding).

Comment: @Srikanth : You need to read these: [IEEE Floating Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) and [Fraction to Binary Conversion](http://cs.furman.edu/digitaldomain/more/ch6/dec_frac_to_bin.htm).

Comment: The observed and complained-about behavior is not caused by the error in representing .1. It is caused by the error in converting the `double` `0.1 * j` to `float` when assigning to `broj`. “-0.0” would not be printed if `broj` were `double`, even though the representation error for .1 would still be present.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the print statement:

```
printf ("%3.1f ", broj-(float)(j*0.1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Too understand what is going on you can made little changes to you program. According to the default argument promotions rules from C standard `printf()` promotes `float` to `double`. Thus we can take a look on what is going on with numbers in the operations in `double` format (more fraction part digits):

```
        while (j>=0) {
            printf ("%3.18lf ", j*0.1);
            printf ("%3.18lf ", broj);
            printf ("%3.18lf ", broj - j*0.1);
            /*printf ("%3.18lf ", (double)(broj-(j*0.1)));*/
                        break;
            j--;
        }
```

The output:

```
9
0.000000000000000000 0.000000000000000000 0.000000000000000000  0. red
0.100000000000000006 0.100000001490116119 0.000000001490116114  1. red
0.200000000000000011 0.200000002980232239 0.000000002980232228  2. red
0.300000000000000044 0.300000011920928955 0.000000011920928938  3. red
0.400000000000000022 0.400000005960464478 0.000000005960464455  4. red
0.500000000000000000 0.500000000000000000 -0.000000000000000028  5. red
0.600000000000000089 0.600000023841857910 0.000000023841857877  6. red
0.700000000000000067 0.699999988079071045 -0.000000011920928994  7. red
0.800000000000000044 0.800000011920928955 0.000000011920928911  8. red
0.900000000000000022 0.899999976158142090 -0.000000023841857960  9. red
```

Output shows **effects caused by finite precision of numbers**. Thus third column is supposed to be consisting of zeros only but it doesn't, because of this effect.